# Segmentation fault 11 while loop, but it seems there is no index out of bound

Tags: segmentation-fault, c++20

I'm having trouble understanding why my c++ code causes a:

> segmentation fault: 11

I have found at which line the error occurs but I still have no idea what is the problem.

```
double time_MC_loop[]={0.0, 0.0};
while(order_loop<=order-1 and T()<time_MC)
  {
      order_loop+=1;
      if (order_loop!=order)
      {
          time_MC_loop[1]+=time_MC*pow(3.0,(double)order_loop-order-1);
          time_MC_loop[0]=time_MC*pow(3.0,(double)order_loop-order-1);
      }
      else
      {
          time_MC_loop[0]=-time_MC_loop[1]+time_MC;
          time_MC_loop[1]=time_MC;
      }
      
     //here I'm skipping parts of the code where I don't use either T() or time_MC_loop
      
      bool still_time=T()<time_MC_loop[1];
      cout<<still_time;
      
      //when I write "exit(1);" here, I don't get a segmentation fault, 
      //and the program prints the expected value of the boolean still_time
      
      while(still_time)
      {
         exit(1);
         // However, I get a segmentation fault here, so it seems the bug occurs in the while test.
       //...
       }
```

Here `T()` is a timer that is defined in a library written by one of my colleagues. It returns a double that represents how long the program have been running for since the command `T.ini()` and until the command `T.fin()`. I have used it several times and it have never caused me such an issue, so I don't think it causes the problem.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, usage of C++20 suggets you use a fairly new toolchain. Have you tried compiling with address sanitizer on (`-fsanitize=address` in case of GCC and Clang)?

Comment: While trying to create a minimal reproducible example, I have found the error: the segmentation fault happened with a completely unrelated variable within the first while loop in my code above but somehow it did not print the error at this line.

Comment: If something had wrote to illegal (formally) memory location before, it may cause seg faults or allocation\deallocation errors _after_ the fact because of memory content corruption.

Comment: If you have found the problem, please post it as an answer and mark that answer as accepted. Yes you can (and should) answer your own questions. Please don't add "solved" to the title.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error: the segmentation fault happened with a completely unrelated variable within the first while loop in my code above but somehow it did not print the error at this line.